# R logistic regression rounding errors?

Tags: r

I'm just learning about logistic regression in R, and have come across something confusing.  I have a large dataset with two predictor variables which I use to train a logit model.

```
> model <- glm(as.factor(traintrain$loss)~.,data=traintrain[,-ncol(traintrain),with=FALSE],family=binomial)
Warning message:
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred 
> traintest$pred <- predict(model, traintest[,!"loss",with=FALSE],type="response")
```

Here's the output of my model

```
> model

Call:  glm(formula = as.factor(traintrain$loss) ~ ., family = binomial, 
    data = traintrain[, -ncol(traintrain), with = FALSE])

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         f527         f528  
 -2.4123661   -0.0001938    0.0001938  

Degrees of Freedom: 53804 Total (i.e. Null);  53802 Residual
Null Deviance:      34540 
Residual Deviance: 32740    AIC: 32750
```

Here's what my test dataset looks like

```
> traintest
             f527      f528 loss       pred
    1:  512556.00  512690.3    0 0.08359656
    2:  516634.38  516635.0    0 0.08162884
    3: 7261975.82 7262170.0    0 0.07658846
    4: 1289936.09 1290091.5    0 0.08297042
    5:  474396.88  476308.0    0 0.11410204
   ---                                     
23056:  362651.53  362950.3    0 0.08625780
23057: 1590119.98 1590853.3    0 0.09150362
23058:  124814.17  125030.8    0 0.08530484
23059:  346397.91  346536.2    0 0.08385799
23060:   85503.97   85504.0    0 0.08213298
```

As you can see, the model stuck a .08359 probability of success on my first test data point.  As a sanity check, I wanted to plug the model coefficients into the [logistic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#Logistic_function.2C_odds_ratio.2C_and_logit) along with my first test observation and make sure I came out with the same result.  This is what I got

```
> 1/(1+exp(-(-2.4123661-0.0001938*512556.00+0.0001938*512690.3)))
[1] 0.08422038
```

It's off by about .001.  I've noticed a number of other discrepancies that seem sort of high like this.  Is this just rounding error or am I making a fundamental mistake?  Thanks

Comment: I've never seen anyone subset data like this

Comment: R is retaining more digits than it displays.

Comment: Take a look at `?options`. in particular, look at the section in the help file for `digits` and `scipen`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sum( c(1, 512556.00, 512690.3) * coef(model) )
```

Thanks for the checkmark but this next suggestion probably wouldn't work even though I suggested it in my first posting. For two reasons. The first is that the output from traintest looks to be from a data.table object and because it doesn't include the '1' that is needed to represent the baseline to be multiplied by the `(Intercept)` value in `coef()`'s return.

```
sum( traintest[1, ] * coef(model) )
```